# local.ERROR: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist

Tags: laravel, eloquent

acabo de crear un filtro muy sencillo con Ajax y Laravel.

Solo son 4 opciones, el filtro funciona bien, pero cuando dejo ambas fechas vacías, From, To, manda error 500 Internal Server Error

```
 private function searchCierre($from = null, $to = null, $asesor = NULL, $type = NULL ) 
    {
        $cierre = Cierre::all();

        if($from && $to){
            $cierre = Cierre::whereDate('created_at', '>=', $from)
            ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $to);
        }

        if($asesor) {
            $cierre = $cierre->where('asesor_id',$asesor);
        }

        if($type) {
            $cierre = $cierre->where('operation_type',$type);
        }

        return $cierre->paginate(100);
    }
```

No entiendo porqué hace esto, puse todos los argumentos como opcionales en el método, no debería arrojar error

Comment: un error 500 involucra a tu código en el servidor, dado eso abre el log de errores de Laravel y extrae que mensaje se generó ahi

Comment: listo ya lo traduje, el error solo dice Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (

Comment: ¿Es lo único que dice el log de errores de Laravel?, lo encuentras en *storage/logs/laravel.log*

Comment: perdón no vi que pusiste log de laravel, aparece esto [2021-02-12 13:33:41] local.ERROR: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist.

Comment: Listo tu error es por esto: `$cierre = Cierre::all();`, sustituyelo por `Cierre::query()` y debería funcionar

Comment: wow muchísimas gracias, en efecto, ya funciona, gracias compañero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error se soluciona.

Cambiando esto:

```
$cierre = Cierre::all();
```

A esto:

```
$cierre = Cierre::query();
```

Ahora ¿por qué?

1. El uso del método `all()` nos retorna **`\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|static[]`**, ahora si nos dirigimos precisamente a la clase veremos que efectivamente el método `paginate()` no existe dentro de ella
2. Mientras que si usamos al método `query()` nos retorna **`\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`**, si ahora nos dirigimos a dicha clase notaremos que esta si posee la declaración del método `paginate` por ahi de la línea 748 mas o menos así:

   ```
   public function paginate(............................)
   ```

Los métodos de los puntos 1 y 2 los puedes revisar mas a detalle en la clase `Model` que es donde existen y de la cual heredan o extienden tus modelos creados, en este caso el modelo `Cierre`.

Luego entonces al usar el método `query()` podrás iniciar la construcción de la consulta a tu modelo encadenando el resto de métodos que ocupas.